# Getting error while loading the Examples with "superset" user

Tags: apache-superset

Need help, and have searched everywhere for a solution with no luck.

We are using Apache Superset 3.1.1 with Postgresql on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and Superset has been installed using Python 3.9. And superset_config.py is loaded with SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql:/dbuser:password@ip_address:port/db'

The issue we are facing is, when we run the below command directly as a root user we are able to load the examples.
Command : superset run -h ip_address -p port_no --with-threads --reload --debugger

But when I run the same command as Superset User I am getting below error when I load the examples.
Unexpected error

Error: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

Need help in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

searched for superset.db file, could'nt find it anywhere. Was thinking that the superset.db file has been created in some location as a root user and the superset user is not able to access the file because of which it is giving this error.